# PHP: how to turn an empty string into null

Tags: php, null, getter, getter-setter

I want to turn an empty input/ string into `null`, but it seems I can't get it work. Below is the class that handles $_POST,

```
class post 
{
    public $data = array();

    public function get($param, $default = null) {
        if (!isset($this->data[$param])) {//not set, return default
            return $default;
        }
        else if(isset($this->data[$param]) && $default === ''){//empty string
            return null;
        }
        return $this->data[$param];
    }

}
```

For instance,

```
$post = new post();
$test = $post->get('url','');
var_dump($test);
```

I get this,

```
string '' (length=0)
```

But I want `null`. Is it possible?

Comment: You are returning `$default` which is '' (first `if`). Where do you actually use `$_POST`?

Comment: The check for `isset($this->data[$param])` is redundant in your `else if`.

Comment: awww thanks for pointing it out. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @konsolebox's answer, you can also silently convert empty strings to `NULL`s inside the `get()` method:

```
public function get($param, $default = null) {
    if ($default === '') {
        $default = null;
    }

    // ...
```

The advantage to this is that when your default is dynamic (passed in as a variable), and it happens to be an empty string, it still produces the desired effect:

```
$default = '';
$test = $post->get('url', $default); // null
```

Comment: Sometimes it's also better not to hardcode it: `$test = $post->get('url', $default === '' ? null : $default);`

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't need to add an argument:

```
$test = $post->get('url');
```

The default for it is `null` after all.

Or else you could explicitly specify it:

```
$test = $post->get('url', null);
```